# Aggregate total sum for like entries in MongoDb using Aggregration framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a huge collection conatins only this kind of documents.

```
  {
        "_id" : "https://example.com/test.html",
        "Count" : 1503.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "http://example.org/gr/",
        "Count" : 715.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "https://example.com/document/d//edit",
        "Count" : 710.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "http://example.org/gr/test.htm",
        "Count" : 429.0000000000000000
    }
}
```

How can I use mongodb aggregation framework to achive this result.

```
 {
        "_id" : "https://example.com/",
        "Count" : 2213.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "http://example.org/",
        "Count" : 1144.0000000000000000
    }
}
```

Specificaly How can I use text serach after split in $project pipeline?

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

First you've got to use `$substr` to only retrieve the beginning of each URI.

Then you should be able to `$group` and `$sum` things up.

The first part might get tricky and/or impossible, because I don't know of any operator that returns *the position of the third slash* in a string.

---

Though my suggestion would be to rewrite the code, in order to split the string before you insert it. i.e.

```
{
  id: ObjectId("..."),
  domain: "http://example.com",
  path: "test.html",
  count: 1503
}
```

When subdomains should also be accessible, I'd go or something like:

```
{
  id: ObjectId("..."),
  uri: "http://sub.example.org/foo.html",
  protocol: "http",
  subdomain: "sub",
  domain: "example.org",
  path: "foo.html",
  count: 1503
}
```

This of course may be slower on insert, but you can query a lot of stuff.